# How to delete files in folder automatically on centos 7

Tags: cron, centos, centos7

I have 2 folders / directorys and in the folders there are many files and then I would like to delete all files in the folders automatically using schedule on centos 7 (If more 1 day the files automatically delete)

- /var/log/web

  - /var/log/web/log1.log
  - /var/log/web/log2.log
  - /var/log/web/log3.log
- /var/log/http

  - /var/log/http/http1.log
  - /var/log/http/http2.log

Big thanks if you reply this question. 
Best Regards

Comment: You shouldn't use cron for this, but [`logrotate`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/logrotate.conf.5.html).

Comment: Hi @BenjaminW. Thanks for your replied, I am going to learn about it.